# Why am I losing the color profile when GIMP invokes Darktable?

Tags: color-management, darktable, gimp

When gimp 2.10.32 opens a raw file using darktable 4.0.1 via the plugins/file-darktable/file-darktable plugin, my image has the color profile assigned to it that I want.  (I have a preset for the darktable input color profile module that matches my camera).  However, after exiting darktable and loading into gimp, the image has the sRGB profile from gimp.  Why is this happening?  Shouldn't the image still be using the color profile assigned in darktable?

I have gimp's Image Import and Export preference set to "Ask what to do"; if I open a .jpg file which has a color profile assigned in gimp, gimp asks me whether to convert it or not.

Comment: Is there a profile in the image exported by Darktable?

Comment: @xenoid  I don't know if there's a profile in the image or not.  GIMP uses a plugin to invoke darktable, so I don't see the exported image.  At least I don't know where it is.  I know if I run darktable alone the image has a profile in it.